# Как распарсить массив структур в json с помощью библиотеки nlohmann/json?

Tags: c++, json, парсер

Мне нужно распарсить json файл с помощью библиотеки nlohmann. Проблема в том, что я не знаю как распарсить массив структур.
Если массив состоит из базовых типов, к примеру интов, тут все понятно

```
{
  "list" : [
    1, 2, 3, 4
  ]
}
```

Этот список парсится так

```
 std::vector<int> list;
 test["list"].get_to<std::vector<int>>(list);
```

Но как быть, если массив состоит из сложных структур и выглядит как то так?

```
{
  "list" : [
    {
      "a" : 1,
      "b" : 2
    },
    {
      "a" : 2,
      "b" : 1
    }
  ]
```

}

Comment: ручками, ручками, автоматом не получится

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого необходимо объявить свою структуру и написать для нее соотв. функции [де]сериализации c сигнатурами `void from_json(json const & j, my_type & p)` и `void to_json(json & j, my_type const & p)`.

После этого появится возможность работать с объектами этого типа аналогично встроенным `std::vector<my_type> list; test["list"].get_to<std::vector<my_type>>(list);`

Comment: Т.е написать класс, в котором будет функция член, десереализующая в него json? Или как сделать так, чтоб он понимал какую функцию юзать

Comment: @DenverToha Нет, это должны быть свободные функции в том же пространстве имен, что и класс, по аналогии с операторами << >>

Comment: т.е, в функции должно быть что то типа
my_type.a = list[a]
и тд?